# Regular expression for string to find only number without decimal point.

Tags: c#

From a paragraph in document, need to find only digit 1.
There are strings 1, 1.3, 1.8. do want to select 1 and not 1.3.

Also need to find digit not followed by - or / or any other special character.

Comment: And what have you tried doing?

Comment: Try http://regexr.com/ to help you out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expression:

```
(?:\s)[0-9]+(?:[\s,])
```

That is whitespace either side of the number, each in a none capturing group, and the group [0-9] one or more times. At the end of the number it can be a whitespace character or a comma, add more items to expand the group.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
^(\d+)(?!\.)
```

[Live example](https://regex101.com/r/0NFQOH/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find first digit you can use `^-?(\d)`.
If you want to find number before point you can use `^-?(\d)+`.